# Performance Issue with IN operator in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

How to fix the performance issue with the in operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Q1 
WHERE Q1.sample IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE 
                    FROM TABLE(APEX_STRING.SPLIT(NVL(:P34_ACC,Q1.sample ),',')))
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a function to generate rows in your `IN` clause. Oracle cannot know whether this will result in say, one or two rows or five billion rows. Thus it can only come up with a general execution plan, that may or may not be good.

You can hint Oracle as to the number of expected rows using the undocumented `CARDINALITY` hint:

```
SELECT *
FROM Q1 
WHERE Q1.sample IN 
(
  SELECT /*+cardinality(t, 10)*/ COLUMN_VALUE 
  FROM TABLE( APEX_STRING.SPLIT(NVL(:P34_ACC,Q1.sample ),',')) t
);
```

For the case of few rows, you should have an index on `Q1.sample`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON q1(sample);
```